# Create a JSON file from a Flask view to be used with D3

Tags: python, pandas, d3.js, flask, jinja2

I need to use a JSON file created by one of the views in some D3 code in a template.  I can load the file with D3 with

```
d3.json("nameOfTheFile.json", function (error, data) {
  // ...
}
```

How can I create and serve this file from a Flask view? When I run the same script from IPython notebook I export the file with

```
dataFrame.to_json(nameOfTheFile.json, orient='records', date_format='iso')
```

but that instruction does not work from the view.

Comment: Thanks. I didn´t remember to write the code in that way.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need (or want) to write anything to a file here.  You can create the JSON and return it from a flask method:

```
from flask import Flask, Response

@app.route('/getMyJson')
def getMyJson():
    json = dataFrame.to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso')
    response = Response(response=json, status=200, mimetype="application/json")
    return(response)
```

The `d3` then becomes:

```
d3.json("/getMyJson", function (error, data) {
  // ...
  // Operations with those data
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That is what I'm looking for. Thanks so much.